# Predicate and SortDescriptor in Swift 3

Tags: swift3, xcode8-beta4

I can't find anything about this in the release notes or on swift.org, but what they're gone now. What happened to them in the Xcode Beta 4?

Answer (score 2):

[`NSPredicate`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nspredicate) and [`NSSortDescriptor`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nssortdescriptor) are still around in Xcode 8 beta 4; they've just got their "NS" back after losing it in previous betas.

According to [SE-0086](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0086-drop-foundation-ns.md), which covers dropping the "NS" prefix from certain Foundation types in Swift 3, `NSPredicate` is an example of the set of types keeping "NS" because they're likely to be replaced by [value types](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0069-swift-mutability-for-foundation.md) in the not too distant future. `NSSortDescriptor` isn't given as an example in that proposal, but it's easy to image that it might fall into the same group.